# unable to complie C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I can't compile my C code as the compiler giving the following error:

> can't create C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8DmycR.o: Permission
>   denied.

Any suggestion ? how to give the compiler the permission ?

Comment: Why are you compiling in that directory?

Comment: I suppose you're using an IDE to compile for you and have no idea (no offense intended) how to use `gcc` to compile to a different directory? You may want to post more information about your OS, IDE, etc. so we can tell you how to change the options. But research first please.

Comment: then where should i compile?

Comment: Show both your code (as some [MCVE]) and your compilation command (you'll better type some compilation command when asking here, and you need to show that command with your source code in the question). Your question is off-topic.

Comment: No im not using any IDE and Windows10. But even with IDE Im getting the same error and i dont know how to compile in a diffrent directory . Please tell me how can i do that

Comment: It is both operating system specific and compiler specific. So we cannot help. Take several hours to dive into the documentation of your compiler and of your operating system

Comment: Im using gcc filename.c

Comment: Read gcc documentation to see how to change output path.

Comment: is filename.c in this directory?If yes put it in a different directory and use the same command

Comment: How can I change the directory ?

Comment: Take the source file - filename.c, put it in a different directory and use the same command

Comment: BTW, read carefully [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).  You should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g filename.c -o progname` and you should [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: why are you even compiling in windows ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you don't have the permissions to create/write to this folder. One solution would be to run your IDE as an administrator. If you compile from the command line, you could run the command line as an administrator. While this would be the simplest solution, it wouldn't be the best one. The better solution would be to set the right permissions for the folder. For windows, you can navigate to the folder, right click it, click properties, security, click edit. Allow your user to write to that folder. I don't use windows by myself, so this may vary, but a quick google should show you how to set write permissions on your OS.

Comment: i have already given r/w permission to the folder but still the problem is not solved